# How to perform marker based correction of data frame in R (cross-referencing data frames)?

Tags: r, dplyr, transformation, tidyverse

users,

I am trying to alter a set of data (set A) based on values in another dataset (set B). Both share a counter variable (TS) that is almost identical (with some deviations due to different rounding – unfortunately unavoidable). Furthermore, entries in both set have different frequencies (making A longer than B).

Here is an example for set A:

```
setA <- tibble(TS = c(rep(2.0913, 4), rep(2.123, 5)),
           AF3_S = 1:9,
           AF4_S = 1:9)

> setA
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     TS AF3_S AF4_S
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1  2.09     1     1
2  2.09     2     2
3  2.09     3     3
4  2.09     4     4
5  2.12     5     5
6  2.12     6     6
7  2.12     7     7
8  2.12     8     8
9  2.12     9     9
```

Here is an example for set B:

```
setB <- tibble(TS = c(2.09131, 2.12304),
               AF3_Q = c(1,4),
               AF4_Q = c(3,0))

> setB
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     TS AF3_Q AF4_Q
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2.09  1.00  3.00
2  2.12  4.00  0
```

What I want to do, is remove entries in set A, whenever the marker in set B is smaller than 2. I.e. the result in this case here should look like:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     TS AF3_S AF4_S
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1  2.09    NA     1
2  2.09    NA     2
3  2.09    NA     3
4  2.09    NA     4
5  2.12     5    NA
6  2.12     6    NA
7  2.12     7    NA
8  2.12     8    NA
9  2.12     9    NA
```

I've tried completing this with a for loop. However, since the actual files are very long (A ~ 1,5Mio rows, B ~ 50K rows), too many iterations were required, which is why looping is out of the question.

Would anyone happen to have an idea on how to solve this? I would also be interested in reading material to learn more about how to handle these kinds of problems efficiently in R.

Thank you and best regards

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data

```
setA <- tibble(TS = c(rep(2.0913, 4), rep(2.123, 5)),
           AF3_S = 1:9,
           AF4_S = 1:9)

setB <- tibble(TS = c(2.09131, 2.12304),
               AF3_Q = c(1,4),
               AF4_Q = c(3,0))
```

The first thing you'll have to decide is when two `double`s are 'equal`. Let's say
values are equal when up to the 2nd decimal digit matches, you can use

```
round(setA$TS * 100) == round(setB$TS[1] * 100)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now we can use `match` to return the row-indices of `setB$TS` that matches `setA$TS`

```
I <- match(round(setA$TS*100), round(setB$TS*100))
I
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

Note that the length of `I` is equal to the number-of-rows of `setA` but the values are the row-indices of `setB`

Then for each column we use `ifelse` to return a conditional value

```
setA$AF3_S <- ifelse(setB$AF3_Q[I] < 2, NA, setA$AF3_S)
setA$AF4_S <- ifelse(setB$AF4_Q[I] < 2, NA, setA$AF4_S)
setA

# A tibble: 9 x 3
     # TS AF3_S AF4_S
  # <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1  2.09    NA     1
# 2  2.09    NA     2
# 3  2.09    NA     3
# 4  2.09    NA     4
# 5  2.12     5    NA
# 6  2.12     6    NA
# 7  2.12     7    NA
# 8  2.12     8    NA
# 9  2.12     9    NA
```

Comment: Dear CPak, that was an easy and feasible solution, thank you! One remaining question: How would I go about doing this more generalized if I had 14 instead of just 2 data columns?